# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[-0.32062087,0.27050002,......]'

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, word2vec, sentiment-analysis

My dataframe has columns where one has list of float values. When I train that column as X_train, I showing cannot string to float or tensorflow float data type.

DataSet:

[image: DataSet]

I tried this:

```py
df['sent_to_vec'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
```

or nested for loop to convert values in float type; but didn't get executed.

Comment: It seems you have a string containing letters that look like a JSON array, for example. Not a JSON array, and not numbers.

Comment: What is the output of `df[["sent_to_vec"]].dtypes`? Check that column for any consistency - if it contains non-float values.

Comment: sent_to_vec    object
dtype: object

Comment: it only have positive and negative float number

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a string that's really just a floating-point number to the Python `float()` function:

```py
f1 = float('0.1')
print(f1)
```

It works.

Try passing a string that's not just a floating-point number, but is instead some sort of array or list representation with multiple numbers separated by other punctuation:

```py
f2 = float('[0.1, 0.2]')
print(f2)
```

You'll get the same error as you're asking about. That string, `'[0.1, 0.2]'` is not a representation of a floating-point number that `float()` can read.

You should look for a function that can read a string like `'[0.1, 0.2]'`. Can you see the code that wrote the `Vectorized data.csv` file? (Did you write that code, or that file?)

You'll want to use some function that does the reverse of whatever wrote that column of the file.

Comment: Thanks i understood things you mentioned above and it is True. As you ask for code which wrote that float values was actually right it returned that values in floating point numbers but i pushed all arrays to pandas series. pd.Series taken that as string. But still i did not got output. BTW thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you see the code that wrote the `'Vectorized data.csv file'`? Did you write that code, or that file? You need to do the exact reverse of how it was written to read it back in.